# In Magento 2.2.6 in addtocart.phtml, how can I get the "Qty Increments"

Tags: magento, magento2

In Magento 2.2.6 from the file

```
"/app/design/frontend/THEME/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml"
```

How can I get the "Qty Increments" that I set as in the screenshot?

I have done a lot of tests but they do not work, for example:

```
<?php echo $product->getStockItem()->getData('qty_increments') ?>
<?php echo $block->getProductQtyIncrements() ?>
<?php echo $stockItem->getQtyIncrements() ?>
<?php echo $product->getStockItem()->getQtyIncrements() ?>
```

[Screenshot Qty Increments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQRt9.png)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the stock status please proceed as follows :

In the addtocart BLock add following in the constructor :

```
\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository $stockItemRepository,
```

and then initiate it as

```
$this->_stockItemRepository = $stockItemRepository;
```

then you can create a method like :

```
public function getStockItem($productId)
{
    return $this->_stockItemRepository->get($productId);
}
```

and call this from the the template file to get all stock related information of the product.

I suggest to over-ride the block file and then do above suggested changes in it.

Let me know if i was able to help.

Comment: I tried to modify "StockItemRepository.php" directly (after I will think about overriding).
But already only by editing "StockItemRepository.php" I get this error (404): 
https://ibb.co/mfEun0

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for Magento 2.2 and above, using the View models approach.
Documentation: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/view-models.html

## Create a custom module with the following files

**app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Vendor\ModuleName\ViewModel\Qty" />
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_ModuleName" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional" template="Vendor_ModuleName::product/view/addtocart.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Vendor\ModuleName\ViewModel\Qty</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart" template="Vendor_ModuleName::product/view/addtocart.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Vendor\ModuleName\ViewModel\Qty</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/ViewModel/Qty.php**

There is no need to create a custom function, since it is enough to extend the "Qtyincrements" Class.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\ViewModel;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Block\Qtyincrements;

class Qty extends Qtyincrements implements ArgumentInterface {}
```

**app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml**

Now your are able to access the getProductQtyIncrements() via the viewModel like this:

```
...
<?php $viewModel = $block->getViewModel(); ?>
<?php $productQtyIncrements = $viewModel->getProductQtyIncrements(); ?>
...
```

Hope this is useful to future readers. Leave a upvote if it worked for you.